# How to measure small current in high voltage environment?

Tags: voltage, current

I would like to measure the current in a circuit with very high DC voltage. The maximum current produced by the source is 0.5mA, and the maximum voltage is 25kV.

I know that I can measure current using a hall sensor, but it's too expensive for my experiment.

I can also measure the voltage drop across a known resistance, but I'm unsure over how exactly I should calculate the resistance. Using Ohm's Law the resistance is 50MΩ, but I don't know if that's the correct way of doing it.

Any other cheap and conventional methods for me to measure said current?

Comment: if a hall sensor is too expensive, what cost is OK for you? I feel that whatever we propose, you'll say "too expensive". State a maximum prize, or drop the "too expensive".

Comment: What's the minimum current you need to measure? What's the minimum voltage?

Comment: also, your 50 MΩ are very wrong. Don't know where these come from, and you don't say how you arrived there.

Comment: "The maximum current produced by the source is 0.5mA, and the maximum voltage is 25kV." Produced simultaneously? i.e. 25KV @ 0.5mA. Or is that 25kV at no load (open circuit) and a maximum of 0.5mA at short circuit? Or something else?

Comment: And: if this is an experiment, why not Z̶o̶i̶d̶b̶e̶r̶g̶ use a Multimeter on the low side, assuming the 25kV are referenced to ground?

Comment: Sounds like you need a classic 0-1 mA meter and some strong glasses so you can stand well back.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - 25 kV over 0.5 mA is 50 M. The kid doesn't have the faintest idea what he's doing.

Comment: Yes, a simple 1ma analog panel meter will do the job, but it's the 25kV that needs more explanation of context.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: If you have to ask such a basic question, you should not be playing with such high voltages. **But if you *must* kill yourself, you're doing so at your own risk.** That being out of the way,

\$U = I \cdot R\$,

Therefore, if you use a 10 kΩ resistor,

\$U = 0.0005 \,\text A \cdot 10000\, Ω = 5 \,\text V\$.

This is the voltage you will measure at 0.5 mA. In other words, a 10 kΩ resistor will give you 10 V per mA.

Other factors like for instance impedances at the supply or load side, can throw this number off by a significant amount, but since you have not said anything about the circuit in question, all that stuff is impossible to address.

Best of luck. By the way, remember to write your last will *before* you start. Your widow will thank you for it. And consider filling in a donor card, just in case any of your organs make it through.

Comment: Let's be realistic. OP sounds like they're young. If the supply is actually able to deliver 0.5 mA at 25 kV (which is pure guesswork, here), that source will break down when in contact with a mere 200 kΩ body resistance. So, a solid electrical shock, but if youth is good for anything, the heart rhythm might actually recover from that, and chances are that the involuntary movement destroys the experiment, thus making it safe. I'll give OP a 70% chance of survival, easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an ammeter, The easiest way to measure this is to insert 1k on the return side and measure the voltage drop of 0.5V per 500 uA full scale

The generator will have capacitance so arc current will be much higher than 500uA.  if you are concerned about dielectric breakdown and excess current. then add Carbon spark plug wire for safety to limit current or use a string of resistors rated for 25kV.

I found this method useful for Modifyng a HIPOT to be non-destructive on device insulation failures.   You may be testing for ESD failures.  Just be aware of dielectric breakdown currents.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's start at the top.

> Using Ohm's Law the resistance is 50MΩ, but I don't know if that's the
>   correct way of doing it.

That one made my blood run cold. While it's true that 25 kV divided by 0.5 mA gives 50 Megohms, that number is almost completely unrelated to your question, and suggests that you are really, really clueless about what you're doing - and I'm not trying to put you down or make fun of you: I'm trying to save your life.

So what you need is not advice from the internet. You desperately need to talk to someone with experience who will (after going pale) walk you through how to handle high voltage without dying. At your level of understanding, almost anything you do has the potential for you to do it wrong, and wrong in this case means Bad Things Will Happen. You simply don't know what's important and what isn't, so any description you provide of what you're doing is untrustworthy.

Please. Find somebody who can help you in person.